# JSReport Docker Container not writing to data folder

Tags: javascript, docker, persist, jsreport

I have been trying to create a docker image of Jsreport that persists even after it is stopped. However, no matter what I try, templates and work done in the portal that the image is running does not save to the data directory.

I have tried running the image and mounting the data directory that it is stored in

```sh
docker run -p 5483:5483 -v /mydata:/DOCKERJSREPORT/data jsreport-container
```

I have tried adding the property "Storage Path" In the Store Object of the config file:

```json
"store": {
      "provider": "fs",
      "storagePath": "/DOCKERJSREPORT/data"
    },
```

And I have tried adding JSREPORT as a USER in my docker file:

```docker
USER jsreport
```

It runs with these and even loads all the stored custom templates from the data directory, but does not save or persist new ones. I'm at a lost please help!

Here is my full DockerFile in case it's needed:

```docker
FROM jsreport/jsreport:3.13.0

USER jsreport

COPY --chown=jsreport:jsreport jsreport.config.json /app
COPY --chown=jsreport:jsreport /data /app/data

RUN npm install handlebars-intl --save
```

this is what my hierarchy looks like:

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: I think you've got your volume mount wrong. The format is `<host-path>:<container-path>`. Unless `/mydata` is an actual, valid host-path, it won't work. Perhaps you meant `-v $PWD/data:/DOCKERJSREPORT/data`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I believe that I was doing this wrong as well, but I did try this before and it did not work. I get this error:  Error occurred during reporter init: Error: Error when loading extension fs-store@3.2.5
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/data/storage'

Answer (score 0):

the straight way to make it persist the data is mounting a volume that targets `/app/data`. there is no need to modify the configuration `store.provider. storagePath` (unless you want a different location **inside the container**), also no need that you copy manually the data folder on the Dockerfile.

the steps that work are the following:

- Dockerfile

```
    FROM jsreport/jsreport:3.13.0
    COPY --chown=jsreport:jsreport jsreport.config.json /app
    RUN npm install handlebars-intl --save
```

- build your custom docker image as usual, with a command like this (assuming your working directory when running this command is your `DOCKERJSREPORT` project)

```bash
    docker build . -t custom-jsreport-3.13.0
```

- run the image (assuming your working directory when running this command is your `DOCKERJSREPORT` project)

```bash
docker run -p 5488:5488 -v ./data:/app/data custom-jsreport-3.13.0
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! When I use your settings and command however, I get this error:  Error occurred during reporter init: Error: Error when loading extension fs-store@3.2.5
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/data/storage'

Comment: i see, i've fixed this issue recently on jsreport v4 docker images, check this https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport/issues/1045 for reference, and the commit that solves it https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport/commit/60533e22e55e67c403f6d0cad0c2c1f4e5ecbc37.

i guess i can give you updated dockerfile to make it work, but it will be even better if you can just use jsreport v4 directly. perhaps try to use v4, but if not possible let me know and i can later update your dockerfile to the extra steps to avoid the EACCES error.